# Ruby rails - drop down size properties

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to give size properties to a drop down and select a default value. Doesn't seem to work, on the html I see `length="35"` but it has no effect on the actual width. How do I do this?

```
@roles = ['admin','user']
collection_select(:user, :title, roles.all, :id, :name, :value => "user", {:length => 35})
collection_select(:user, :title, roles.all, :id, :name, :value => "user", {:width => 35})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `:style => "width:200px"` instead of :length.

Or much better, to use a css class for that selection box.

Comment: Thanks that worked now! I tried this earlier, didn't work that time. May be I did something wrong.